# Ecto Changeset - How to validate that a field contains only numbers and accepts one decimal point

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto

I'm an Elixir beginner.

I am trying to validate a field for employee working hours. I have an input with an attribute of `type="number"`, however this attribute does not fully work for Internet Explorer 11 so I need back end validation to have browser compatability.

The requirements are:

1. The field should only ever contain numbers, non-numerical characters should not be valid.
2. The field is allowed a maximum of one decimal point with a step of 0.5

For example:

- "40" should be **valid**
- "37.5" should be **valid**
- "40 Hours" should be **invalid**
- "32.3" should be **invalid**
- "37.55" should be **invalid**
- "37..5" should be **invalid**

Here's all I got so far:

```
defp validate_working_hours(changeset) do

changeset
|> Changeset.validate_number(:working_hours, greater_than: 0)

end
```

How would I go about validating my requirements? I presume `validate_format` would come in useful here - something along the lines of

`|> Changeset.validate_format(:working_hours, <something here>)`

But after fiddling around I can't seem to validate these requirements. Any help appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after [`Ecto.Changeset.validate_format/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_format/4)

```elixir
...
|> validate_format(:working_hours, ~r/^\d+(?:\.[05])?$/)
```

This regular expression means *at least one digit, followed by an optional dot with either zero or five*.

---

*Sidenote:* please note, that if you ever suppose making this application to be used worldwide, many countries use e. g. the comma (`,`) for decimal separator and the code must be more cumbersome involving locales.